# sort custom date format in yadcf plugin

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I am using jquery Datatables with moment.js and yadcf-plugin.

In my table I have a datefield in the format dd.mm.yyyy - to sort it correctly I use the moment-plugin, this works great.

But in the yadcf-filter, it is sorted as "alpha", like

- 01.09.2020
- 21.05.2019
- 30.04.2020
- 30.08.2025
- 31.12.2017
- 31.12.2021

but I need

- 31.12.2017
- 21.05.2019
- 30.04.2020
- 01.09.2020
- 31.12.2021
- 30.08.2025

How can I sort the values with moment.js?

Thank you.

Comment: You should convert the date to YYYY-MM-DD and put that in a hidden element in front of the visible date. Then the alpabetical sort will work. You can do the conversion with plain javaScript using `Date()`, no nood for `moment` here.

Comment: @lofihelsinki Thank you for the input, I appreciate it. But it isn´t working out for me, I made a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L7e81jhr/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: See **Edit 2** below that answers the actual question.

Seems like adding `sort_as: 'alphaNum'` to the yadcf parameters of the date column would do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD.MM.YYYY' );
  $('#test').dataTable().yadcf([
    {column_number : 0, select_type: 'select'},
    {column_number : 1, select_type: 'select', sort_as: 'alphaNum'}
  ]);
});
```

**EDIT**: If you also want to change the default sorting to the date column, you need add `order`param to the `dataTables`object itself:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD.MM.YYYY' );
  $('#test').dataTable({
    "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
  }).yadcf([
    {column_number : 0, select_type: 'select'},
    {column_number : 1, select_type: 'select', sort_as: 'alphaNum'}
  ]);
});
```

**EDIT 2**: If you want to sort the yadcf select/dropdown, the only option i see is having your own sorting function:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD.MM.YYYY' );
  $('#test').dataTable({
    "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
  }).yadcf([
    {column_number : 0, select_type: 'select'},
    {column_number : 1, select_type: 'select', sort_as: 'custom', sort_as_custom_func: function(one, two) {
        if (moment(one, "DD.MM.YYYY").isAfter( moment(two, "DD.MM.YYYY") )) {return true}
        else {return false}
      }
    }
  ]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it before, but it doesn´t work? See https://jsfiddle.net/L7e81jhr/37/

Comment: Maybe there is a missunderstanding. I mean the sorting in the yadcf-filter: http://xup.in/dl,30980756 The sortorder should be the same like in the datacells (1st entry: 31.12.2017; last entry: 15.08.2025)

Comment: Now i get it. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: return true/false didn't work for me, I used return -1/1